# Fatal error: stm32f4xx_syscfg.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, path, stm32, header-files, truestudio

I am trying to compile this [code](https://github.com/cahya-wirawan/stm32f4-musicplayer) on my `STM32F4Discovery board` using `Atollic True Studio`.

When I launch the debug of the main, I get this error:

```
../lib/driver/src/stm32f4xx_syscfg.c:50:30: fatal error: stm32f4xx_syscfg.h: No such file or directory
```

However `stm32f4xx_syscfg.h` is in the path `/stm32f4-musicplayer/lib/driver/inc`, so I think it's a path issue and I have to specify it somewhere. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the project settings

```
project -> properties -> c/c++ general -> paths and symbols
```

Ensure your `src/` folder is included here.